# The picture in the imageView does not change when the picture changes in the firebase database and storage

Tags: java, android, firebase

What should I do if everything changes when changing the photo in the database, but for some reason it is not displayed in the image view, I use the firebase database, that is, when I register and put a profile photo, everything is fine, it is displayed both in the database and in the imageview, but when I try to change it then it changes in the database and in the storage and in the realtime database the link changes, but in all imageviews the old picture remains, I don’t know why so I checked which link I load in the imageview and output to the console, I don’t understand why. Please help me I don't know what to do

Realtime Database:

```
users:
     "user-uid" {
           "username" : "some-username"
           "level" : "some-level"
           "type" : "some-type"
           "surnameName" : "some-surnameName"
           "email" : "some-email"
           "profileImage": "image-url"
           }
```

Storage:

```
   profileImage{
         "user-uid" - some-img
    }
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView btnAdd, btnHome;
    CircleImageView btnProfile;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mUser.getUid());

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.addRecieptBtn);
        btnHome = findViewById(R.id.homePageBtn);
        btnProfile = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        
        mRef.child("profileImage").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(snapshot.getValue().toString()).into(btnProfile);
                System.out.println(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        btnProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ProfiileActivity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView btnAdd, btnHome;
    TextView level, type, username;
    CircleImageView profile_image, profile_image2;
    ImageButton lg, btnEdit;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    StorageReference sRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mUser.getUid());
        sRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImage");

        level = findViewById(R.id.level);
        type = findViewById(R.id.type);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        profile_image2 = findViewById(R.id.profile_image2);
        lg = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        btnEdit = findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.addRecieptBtn);
        btnHome = findViewById(R.id.homePageBtn);

        mRef.child("profileImage").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(snapshot.getValue().toString()).into(profile_image);
                Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(snapshot.getValue().toString()).into(profile_image2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                username.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("level").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                level.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("type").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                type.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        lg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,EditProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

My EditProfileActivity:

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profile_image;
    AutoCompleteTextView inputCountry;
    EditText inputUsername, inputNameSurname;
    Spinner autocomplete_type, autocomplete_level;
    private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    ImageButton btnSave;
    static String[] autotype = new String[1];
    static String[] autolevel = new String[1];
    static String[] level;
    static String[] type;
    ProgressDialog mLoad;


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    DatabaseReference mRef2;
    StorageReference sRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mUser.getUid());
        sRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImage");
        mLoad = new ProgressDialog(this);
        {// declare all variables here}
        mRef.child("profileImage").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                Glide.with(EditProfileActivity.this).load(uri).into(profile_image);
                System.out.println(uri.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                inputUsername.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("level").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int spinnerPosition = Arrays.asList(level).indexOf(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                autocomplete_level.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("type").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int spinnerPosition = Arrays.asList(type).indexOf(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                autocomplete_type.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("country").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                inputCountry.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        mRef.child("surnameName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                inputNameSurname.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SaveData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SaveData() {
        String username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
        String country = inputCountry.getText().toString();
        String ns = inputNameSurname.getText().toString();
        String level = autolevel[0].toString();
        String type = autotype[0].toString();

        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            inputUsername.setError("Username is required!");
            inputUsername.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else if (username.length() < 3) {
            inputUsername.setError("Min username length should be 3 characters ");
            inputUsername.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else if (country.isEmpty()) {
            inputCountry.setError("Country is required!");
            inputCountry.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else if (ns.isEmpty()) {
            inputNameSurname.setError("Name and Surname is required!");
            inputNameSurname.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else {
            mLoad.setTitle("Setup Profile");
            mLoad.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mLoad.show();
            if (imageUri == null) {
                if (username == null) {
                    mRef.child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            mRef.child("username").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    mRef.child("username").setValue(username);
                }
                if (ns == null) {
                    mRef.child("surnameName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            mRef.child("surnameName").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    mRef.child("surnameName").setValue(ns);
                }
                if (country == null) {
                    mRef.child("country").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            mRef.child("country").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    mRef.child("country").setValue(country);
                }
                mRef.child("level").setValue(level);
                mRef.child("type").setValue(type);
                mLoad.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                sRef.child(mUser.getUid()).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            sRef.child(mUser.getUid()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    if (username == null) {
                                        mRef.child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                mRef.child("username").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        mRef.child("username").setValue(username);
                                    }
                                    if (ns == null) {
                                        mRef.child("surnameName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                mRef.child("surnameName").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        mRef.child("surnameName").setValue(ns);
                                    }
                                    if (country == null) {
                                        mRef.child("country").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                mRef.child("country").setValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        mRef.child("country").setValue(country);
                                    }
                                    mRef.child("level").setValue(level);
                                    mRef.child("type").setValue(type);
                                    mLoad.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            mLoad.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            mLoad.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Something went wrong please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            profile_image.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

My template EditProfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditProfileActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/main_appbar" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputNameSurname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name Surname"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputUsername" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/inputCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Country"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputNameSurname" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_level"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Level"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"></Spinner>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_type"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Type of Food"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/type"></Spinner>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autocomplete_type"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button__3_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="217dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                android:text="Select Your Level:"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/autocomplete_level"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputCountry"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputCountry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Select Type Of Food(that you like):"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/autocomplete_type"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autocomplete_level" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you seeing your onDataChange listeners being triggered after saving the new profile picture?

Comment: @tomerpacific No but i write into onDataChange System.out.println(snapsot.getValue().toString); and a link to the image is displayed in the console every time when somewhere there is image view

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo i post this cоde because when i cut some unnecessary code then people say that on the contrary there is too little code and here is not so difficult code

Comment: @tomerpacific and plus it happens with imageview with textview everything changes